# Putting the number of duplicate post title in a blog with jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I'm learning Jekyll and wanted to share a small blog I made using it but I was wondering if it is possible to put a number of duplicate if the post have the same title, as follows:

Ipsum

Lorem ipsum (2)

Lorem

Lorem ipsum (1)

Obviously without writing the number in the markdown file.

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  <h1 class="post-title">
    <a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
  </h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you!